# JSON - Unable to access value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am accessing data from a json file and I'm getting back an error saying `Cannot read property 'name' of null` .

Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

The JSON below is an example of the response. I have an object and the first value, `items` is an array which has the following values in each index:

```
tracks: {
items: [
    {
        "track": {
            "album": {
                "id": "3yydOEq4GAnXWrJfXDmgzj",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27348185549d7922c1dc319b4d6",
                    },
                ],
                "name": "Kanske var vi rätt bra ändå",
                "release_date": "2020-04-24",
            },
            "artists": [
                {
                    "id": "5wXRHaEx8AvtUv0gyZHGf6",
                    "name": "Newkid",
                }
            ],
            "duration_ms": 153580,
            "id": "1wgHPGGJVV9orCIT99cFMu",
            "name": "Kanske var vi rätt bra ändå",
        },
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to access the name of the track from this but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone help? This is what I'm trying:

```
tracks.items.map(each => ({
    name: each.track.name
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tracks =  {
items: [
    {
        "track": {
            "album": {
                "id": "3yydOEq4GAnXWrJfXDmgzj",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27348185549d7922c1dc319b4d6",
                    },
                ],
                "name": "Kanske var vi rätt bra ändå",
                "release_date": "2020-04-24",
            },
            "artists": [
                {
                    "id": "5wXRHaEx8AvtUv0gyZHGf6",
                    "name": "Newkid",
                }
            ],
            "duration_ms": 153580,
            "id": "1wgHPGGJVV9orCIT99cFMu",
            "name": "Kanske var vi rätt bra ändå",
        },
    }
]
}

console.log(tracks.items.map(each => ({
    name: each.track.name
})))
```

Seems to work. isn't it the result you were looking for ? an array of name:value pairs?

Comment: It may be an issue with the API I am using. I am using Spotify's API to retreive artists and it doesn't return just the name when I am doing this

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I got no idea of what to do with the name accessed, so i just logged it.

```js
tracks.items.map((item) => {
        console.log(item.track.name);
    });
```